# How to delete a single command from history in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, autocomplete, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After some searching online I found that the following command should remove a single entry from the bash history:

```
$ history -d <number>
```

So let's say I would like to remove this single line from my history because I misspelled git
:

```
10003 gti add . && git commit -m
```

When I do the following command:

```
$ history -d 10003
```

It still shows up in my history, even when I restart the terminal

So any idea how I can fix this because I use autocomplete and sometimes especially when using git it can get a bit messy.

Comment: You might also have to remove the entry from the history file, typically at `~/.bash_history`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's solved by deleting the command from `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 7):

Command history in Bash is stored both in-memory, typically for the current shell session, and on disk, by default in `~/.bash_history`. A default history configuration might append the in-memory session to the file on disk when the session is terminated, but there are a lot of knobs to tweak.

To permanently delete a command from history, after running `history -d <number>`, you can run `history -w`. This writes both the in-memory session and any edits to the older history back to the `~/.bash_history` file.

You could also edit the `~/.bash_history` file directly. As long as you *don't* run `history -w` in this case, the older commands will not be touched when the current Bash session exits.

A few references to history settings:

- [`HISTFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILE) – the file where history is persisted (defaults to `~/.bash_history`)
- [`HISTFILESIZE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILESIZE) – the number of commands stored in the history file (defaults to `HISTSIZE`)
- [`HISTSIZE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTSIZE) – the number of commands stored in the (in-memory) history list (defaults to 500)
- [`cmdhist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) – shell option to save multi-line commands in a single history entry
- [`histappend`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) – shell option to control if the history list is appended to the history file, or if the history file is overwritten
- [`lithist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) – shell option to store multi-line commands using linebreaks instead of semicolons

The `-w` option was recommended in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49216) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site.

Comment: How does one change these settings?

Comment: @SherylHohman The variables you can set directly; the shell options are set with `shopt -s <option>`. This typically happens in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin